# How to use "ibmcloud" command on open-tool-chain pipeline.yml

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I'd like to use "ibmcloud" command on devops tool-chain pipeline.yml

can I use this?

I tryed, but pipeline runned not displaying regions

"ibm cloud regions" command sample run.

pipeline build environment no included ibmcloud commands??

```
stages: 
    jobs: 
      - name: dev
        type: deployer
        script: |-
            #!/bin/bash                        
            ibmcloud regions
```

Comment: This toolchain uses ibmcloud commands. They are in separate scripts. https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/secure-file-storage/blob/master/.bluemix/pipeline.yml / https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/secure-file-storage/blob/master/scripts/pipeline-DEPLOY.sh

Comment: thanks @data_henrik I try!